# How to chain an array in mootools?

Tags: mootools, chaining

Say you have an array in mootools:

```
// get the elements and set them as slide
var slideElements = $$('.mySlideElements');
slideElements.set('slide');

// and fire the event -> would slide all elements out at the same time
slideElements.slide('out');
```

How could I put this into a chain to slide them one at a time?

So far I've only succeeded in chaining if I know the exact number of actions I will be performing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up putting a lot of work into this one, chaining was a lot trickier than I thought at first glance.  I've never used it in quite this manner before  :D

You can definitely loop through the `slideElements` array.  Chaining the element events to each other is the tricky part.  I ended up with a loop closure function that loops through each `slideElement` and chains the previous item in the list to the current item:

```
<!-- Working example of chained sliding divs  -->
<div class="mySlideElements" style="background: red" id="slide1">Slide 1</div>
<div class="mySlideElements" style="background: yellow">Slide 2</div>
<div class="mySlideElements" style="background: green">Slide 3</div>
<div class="mySlideElements" style="background: purple">Slide 4</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var slideElements = $$('.mySlideElements');
    slideElements.set('slide');

    for(var i = 1; i < slideElements.length; i++) (function(c1,c2){
        c1.get('slide').chain(function(){c2.slide()});
    })(slideElements[i-1],slideElements[i]);

</script>

<input type="button" onclick="$('slide1').slide()" value="slide"/>
```

Calling `get('slide')` returns the Fx.Slide object that was set on each element, which you can then chain to a function.  My Mootools-fu wasn't strong enough to figure out how to chain it directly to the `slide` property of the next element (which *should* be a function, but it didn't seem to work), so I ended up with the anonymous function you see inside the `chain()` call, which is almost as good.  The loop closure `function(c1,c2)` was necessary to prevent the local `i` loop variable from being out of scope by the time the chained anonymous function got called.

It's set up as a chain reaction for when the first element's `slide` function gets triggered.  If you needed the whole thing to cascade whenever *any* element is clicked, you'd probably want to set every element's `onClick` event to fire the first element's `slide()` and not their own.

Anyway, the code above is a working example.  I hope the results are what you were looking for.

Comment: Its been a long time but unfortunately I had to switch all code to jQuery very shortly after (sad). Nevertheless I took this piece of advice and just tried it now at home. Works perfectly! Thank you very much! Hope it helps all mootoolers out there! ;)

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, this is a better / "mootoolsy" way of doing it. the FX instance provides two possible things that can be used: link: "chain" and onComplete: function. so something like this:

```
var slideEls = function(els) {
    if (!els.length)
        return;

    var lastEl = els.getLast();    
    lastEl.set("slide", {
        duration: "long",
        link: "chain",
        onComplete: function() {
            els.erase(lastEl);
            slideEls(els);
        }
    }).slide("out");
};

slideEls($$('div.mySlideElements'));
```

working example here: http://mootools.net/shell/GmUpM/

this will work with an infinite array length of elements to slide out

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$$('.mySlideElements')
    .set('slide', {
        onComplete: function (el) 
        {
            if (el = el.getParent().getNext ('.mySlideElements'))
                el.slide ('out');
        }
    })
    [0].slide ('out');
```

It just requires that `.mySlideElements` be immediate siblings